# Why is my react form not working as it should?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, express

I'm trying to send data to my database using a react form and it's not working as it should. When I click the button, the function `handleSubmit` is called but it gets an error for some reason.

This is the error I see in the console when I click the button:

[image]

Here is the code for the react form:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ProjectAdminForm = () => {
    const [sdg_desc, setSDGDesc] = useState('')
    const [sdg_num, setSDGNum] = useState('')
    const [goal, setGoal] = useState('')
    const [orginization, setOrginization] = useState('')
    const [source, setSource] = useState('')
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('')
    const [published, setPublished] = useState('')
    const [website_url, setWebsiteURL] = useState('')
    const [assignment_type, setAssignmentType] = useState('')
    const [sharepoint_link, setSharepointLink] = useState('')
    const [statement, setStatement] = useState('')
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() // Prevents refresh of page from happening

        console.log('button clicked')
        const project = {sdg_desc, sdg_num, goal, orginization, source, location, published, website_url, assignment_type, sharepoint_link, statement}
                        
        // Sending form response to backend
        const response = await fetch('/api/projects', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(project),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        const json = await response.json
        

        // Checking for error
        if (!response.ok) {
            setError(json.error)
        }
        if (response.ok) {
            // Reset form inputs back to empty string
            setSDGDesc('')
            setSDGNum('')
            setGoal('')
            setOrginization('')
            setSource('')
            setLocation('')
            setPublished('')
            setWebsiteURL('')
            setAssignmentType('')
            setSharepointLink('')
            setStatement('')
            
            setError(null)
            console.log('new project added', json)
        }
    }

    return (
        <form className="create" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h3>Add a New Project</h3>

            <label>SDG Name:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setSDGDesc(e.target.value)}
                value={sdg_desc}
            />

            <label>SDG Num:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setSDGNum(e.target.value)}
                value={sdg_num}
            />

            <label>Goal:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setGoal(e.target.value)}
                value={goal}
            />

            <label>Orginization:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setOrginization(e.target.value)}
                value={orginization}
            />

            <label>Source:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setSource(e.target.value)}
                value={source}
            />

            <label>Location:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
                value={location}
            />

            <label>Published:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setPublished(e.target.value)}
                value={published}
            />

            <label>Website URL:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setWebsiteURL(e.target.value)}
                value={website_url}
            />

            <label>Assignment Type:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setAssignmentType(e.target.value)}
                value={assignment_type}
            />

            <label>Sharepoint Link:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setSharepointLink(e.target.value)}
                value={sharepoint_link}
            />

            <label>Statement:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setStatement(e.target.value)}
                value={statement}
            />

            <button>Add Project</button>
            {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
        </form>
    )
}

export default ProjectAdminForm
```

Here is the code of the backend api it points too:

```
// create new project
const createProject = async (req, res) => {
    // adding in a new project
    const {sdg_desc, sdg_num, goal, orginization, source, location, published, website_url, assignment_type, sharepoint_link, statement} = req.body
    try {
        const project  = await Project.create({sdg_desc, sdg_num, goal, orginization, source, location, published, website_url, assignment_type, sharepoint_link, statement})
        res.status(200).json(project)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me why when I click the "Add Project" button I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems.
I am gonna assume you are using MongoDB and mongoose, so your code for backend should look like this.

```
const createProject = async (req, res) => {

 const {sdg_desc, sdg_num, goal, orginization, source, location, published, website_url, assignment_type, sharepoint_link, statement} = req.body

const newProject = new Project{(
     sdg_desc: sdg_desc,
     sdg_num : sdg_num,
     goal : goal,
     orginization : orginization,
     source : source,
     location : location,
     published : published,
     website_url : website_url,
     assignment_type : assignment_type,
     sharepoint_link : sharepoint_link,
     statement : statement
)};
    try {
        await newProject.save();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
    }

    res.status(201).json({project: newProject});
}
```

And on the frontend when you are using the fetch API, you need to specify full link to the backend, so it should look like this

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/projects', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(project),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
```

Also make sure that the data you are sending to the backend have the same name on the frontend

Comment: Using your `createProject` function worked, could I ask you why my version didn't?

Comment: You were using .create(), which is used to create documents. .save() is used when you want to save changes into a document, for expamle you can have a document called Posts that holds different posts that users created, when you want to add a new post to it, you would use .save() as you are adding (making changes to the document) a new post to this document. I reccomend looking on the official documentation, my "explanation" might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`<button>Add Project</button>`

Should be

```
<button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Project</button>

or

<button onClick={()=>handleSubmit()}>Add Project</button>
```

You don’t call your function for some reason

I think you can work it out with form like that (but honestly I haven’t seen even single time somebody does it like that in react) but then you have to give something like:

```
<button type=“submit”>…
```

So also I would refactor a bit your bunch of setState:

```
const [state,setState] = useState({});
const handleInputChange = (e) => setState({…state, [e.target.name]:e.target.value});

On inputs:
<input name=“project” onChange={handleInputChange}>…</input>
```

This will give much more flexible state with less code

You should add console.log(req.body)
This would point to source of error

Comment: but don't I call my function at `<form className="create" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`, I get the same error too

Comment: Then you need to add type submit on button (I think)

Comment: You have to kinda bind that button to form, and since you are useState  anyway, having “form” just don’t have any sense…

Comment: And your post request is also handled in react, and not a plain form-data

Comment: Can yo console.log this please const project = {sdg_desc, sdg_num, goal, orginization, source, location, published, website_url, assignment_type, sharepoint_link, statement}

Comment: how could I integrate your method into my code? I don't really understand how I would do that looking at the lines of code you wrote, sorry I'm new to MERN stack development

Comment: console.logging `project` gives me whatever the the values I gave it in the form when I typed it in in a JSON object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246522/discussion-between-soccerball123-and-antokhio).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is coming from your backend, are you using any middlewares, validators like Joi ?

Comment: yes I'm using this code as middleware `const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:4000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};`